# Applying distinct on rdd cosidering both key- value pair and not just on the basis of keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 2 pair RDDs on which I am doing union to give a third RDD.
But resulting RDD has tupes which are repeated:

```
rdd3 = {(1,2) , (3,4) , (1,2)}
```

I want to remove duplicate tuples from `rdd3` but only if both the key value pair of tuple is same. 
How can i do that?

Comment: `rdd3.distinct()`.

Answer (score 1):

Please directly invoke the spark-scala lib api:

```
def distinct(): RDD[T]
```

Remember that it is a generic method with a type parameter.

If you invoke it with your rdd, of type RDD[(Int, Int)], it will give your distinct pairs of type (Int, Int) in your rdd, just as it is.

---

If you want to see the internal of this method. see below for the signature:

```
def distinct(numPartitions: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T] = null): RDD[T] = withScope {
    map(x => (x, null)).reduceByKey((x, y) => x, numPartitions).map(_._1)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct for example

```
    val data= sc.parallelize(
  Seq(
    ("Foo","41","US","3"),
    ("Foo","39","UK","1"),
    ("Bar","57","CA","2"),
    ("Bar","72","CA","2"),
    ("Baz","22","US","6"),
    ("Baz","36","US","6"),
     ("Baz","36","US","6")
  )
  )
```

remove duplicate :

```
 val distinctData = data.distinct()
 distinctData.collect
```